# Stop touch ID from asking for a password

Tags: macos, monterey, settings, touch-id

How do I stop touch ID from asking for a password every few days? Is there a setting controlling this?

I have searched for an answer and have not been able to find any information. I use a MacBook Pro M1, running Monterey. Maybe this is a MacOS 12 bug? But I have not seen anything about touch ID bugs either.

I typically use the Macbook for a few hours, it goes to sleep, for a few hours, or maybe a whole day, and the next activation may or may not ask for a password. I'd rather just use touch ID, all the time (except maybe on reboot).

Any enlightenment to this issue is very welcome.

Comment: If this is a really problematic glitch I would try reinstalling MacOS. First boot into Recovery Mode. On Intel Macs, hold down Cmd+R while booting. On Apple Silicon Macs, power off and then hold down on the power button. You will see Continue holding for startup options. When you see "Loading startup options" let go of the button.

Now select Reinstall MacOS. This will not (I repeat NOT) delete any of your data

Comment: @cashiecoder - it's intentional behaviour, not a glitch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot change the behavior.

From https://support.apple.com/guide/security/face-id-touch-id-passcodes-and-passwords-sec9479035f1/web

> Users can use their passcode or password anytime instead of Face ID or
> Touch ID, but there are situations where biometrics aren’t permitted.
> The following security-sensitive operations always require entry of a
> passcode or password:
>
> Updating the software
>
> Erasing the device
>
> Viewing or changing passcode settings
>
> Installing configuration profiles
>
> Unlocking the Security & Privacy pane in System Preferences on Mac
>
> Unlocking the Users & Groups pane in System Preferences on Mac (if
> FileVault is turned on)
>
> A passcode or password is also required if the device is in any of the
> following states:
>
> The device has just been turned on or restarted.
>
> The user has logged out of their Mac account (or hasn’t yet logged
> in).
>
> The user hasn’t unlocked their device for more than 48 hours.
>
> The user hasn’t used their passcode or password to unlock their device
> for 156 hours (six and a half days), and the user hasn’t used a
> biometric to unlock their device in 4 hours.
>
> The device has received a remote lock command.
>
> The user exited power off/Emergency SOS by pressing and holding either
> volume button and the Sleep/Wake button simultaneously for 2 seconds
> and then pressing Cancel.
>
> There were five unsuccessful biometric match attempts (though for
> usability, the device might offer entering a passcode or password
> instead of using biometrics after a smaller number of failures).
>
> When Face ID with a mask is enabled on an iPhone, it’s available for
> the next 6.5 hours after one of the following user actions:
>
> Successful Face ID match attempt (with or without a mask)
>
> Device passcode validation
>
> Device unlock with Apple Watch
>
> Any of these actions extends the period an additional 6.5 hours when
> performed.

Comment: I feel like my usage ticks all the above boxes, and yet when I wake my laptop from sleep each morning it asks for a password (98%-ish of the time)And on those rare days when it does not, I know the next day it will require passw for sure. However, during the day, it allows the biometric to be used for access. I will dig into this a bit more and report back. Frustrating. But appreciate the list.

Comment: This draconian password reentry requirement is reducing security by making me (and I'm sure most other users) want to switch to a much simple password.